# Transform existing .CSV by comparing previous row with current and minor calculations

Tags: awk, csv

Good day! I have a .CSV file that has 9 columns.  I need to parse its contents into a new file, perform some small calculations and create a new row in the process.  I think this is best illustrated by showing the existing .CSV and the desired output:

**Existing .CSV Contents  (9 columns)**

```
$cat file
Trans #,Type,Date,Num,Name,Memo,Account,Debit,Credit
1321,General Journal,1/4/2013,1127,,Consulting,Cash on Hand,,20.61
,,,,,,IT Services,20.61,
,,,,,,,20.61,20.61
,,,,,,,,
1322,General Journal,7/3/2013,1128,,Utilities,Cash on Hand,,105.5
,,,,,,Utilities,105.5,
,,,,,,,105.5,105.5
,,,,,,,,
1323,General Journal,4/3/2013,1129,,Bell,Cash on Hand,,466.69
,,,,,,Telephone,466.69,
,,,,,,,466.69,466.69
,,,,,,,,
1324,General Journal,1/3/2013,1130,,Consulting,Cash on Hand,,20.61
,,,,,,IT Services,20.61,
,,,,,,,20.61,20.61
,,,,,,,,
1325,General Journal,6/3/2013,1131,,Utilities,Cash on Hand,,79.09
,,,,,,Utilities,79.09,
,,,,,,,79.09,79.09
,,,,,,,,
```

**Desired Output**

```
Trans #,Type,Date,Num,Name,Memo,Account,Debit,Credit
1321,Expense,1/4/2013,1127,0,Consulting,Cash on Hand,,20.61
1321,Expense,1/4/2013,1127,0,Consulting,IT Services,18.24,
1321,Expense,1/4/2013,1127,0,Consulting,HST - Input tax,2.37,
1321,Expense,1/4/2013,1127,0,,,20.61,20.61
1322,Expense,7/3/2013,1128,0,Utilities,Cash on Hand,,105.5
1322,Expense,7/3/2013,1128,0,Utilities,Utilities,93.36,
1322,Expense,7/3/2013,1128,0,Utilities,HST - Input tax,12.14,
1322,Expense,7/3/2013,1128,0,,,105.50,105.5
1323,Expense,4/3/2013,1129,0,Bell,Cash on Hand,,466.69
1323,Expense,4/3/2013,1129,0,Bell,Telephone,413.00,
1323,Expense,4/3/2013,1129,0,Bell,HST - Input tax,53.69,
1323,Expense,4/3/2013,1129,0,,,466.69,466.69
1324,Expense,1/3/2013,1130,0,Consulting,Cash on Hand,,20.61
1324,Expense,1/3/2013,1130,0,Consulting,IT Services,18.24,
1324,Expense,1/3/2013,1130,0,Consulting,HST - Input tax,2.37,
1324,Expense,1/3/2013,1130,0,,,20.61,20.61
1325,Expense,6/3/2013,1131,0,Utilities,Cash on Hand,,79.09
1325,Expense,6/3/2013,1131,0,Utilities,Utilities,69.99,
1325,Expense,6/3/2013,1131,0,Utilities,HST - Input tax,9.10,
1325,Expense,6/3/2013,1131,0,,,79.09,79.09
```

**As you can see in the desired output I need a few new things:**

- Duplicate 1st, 3rd, 5th columns from previous row if next row is `NULL`
- If 5th column in previous row is `NULL` then print `N/A` instead
- Change all entries in 2nd column to `Expense` (from `General Journal`)
- The 8th column (Debit) is the existing value *minus* 13%
- Insert a new row and calculate the HST tax (13%)

---

What have I done so far? I've search all throughout StackExchange and came up with the following ([from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483719/awk-replace-a-pattern-matching-field-with-fields-value-from-previous-row):)

```
    awk '{
       split($0,D,/[^[:space:]]*/);
       s = "";
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
            if($i~/NoData/){ $i =  last[i]; } 
            last[i]=$i ; 
            s = s  sprintf("%s%s",D[i],$i) 
       }  
       print s
 }' file
```

Comment: your "desired"  output looks arbitrary and does not fit your conditions. Here are only some redlines: - no `N/A` values; there are duplicates of `Utilities,Utilities`; - percent calculations are also doubtful. Conclusion: the current "desired" output is not representative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` script *attempts* to implement the operations that you describe:

```
BEGIN   { OFS = FS = "," }

NR == 1 { name = "N/A" }

NR > 1 {
    # use values from previous row if missing
    if ($1 == "") $1 = trans
    if ($3 == "") $3 = date
    if ($5 == "") $5 = name

    $2 = "Expense"

    $9 = 0.13 * $8
    $8 -= $9

    # set values that may be used by the next row
    trans = $1
    date  = $3
    name  = ($5 == "" ? "N/A" : $5)
}

{ print }
```

Running this on the example data that you have supplied:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file.csv
Trans #,Type,Date,Num,Name,Memo,Account,Debit,Credit
1321,Expense,1/4/2013,1127,N/A,Consulting,Cash on Hand,0,0
1321,Expense,1/4/2013,,N/A,,IT Services,17.9307,2.6793
1321,Expense,1/4/2013,,N/A,,,17.9307,2.6793
1321,Expense,1/4/2013,,N/A,,,0,0
1322,Expense,7/3/2013,1128,N/A,Utilities,Cash on Hand,0,0
1322,Expense,7/3/2013,,N/A,,Utilities,91.785,13.715
1322,Expense,7/3/2013,,N/A,,,91.785,13.715
1322,Expense,7/3/2013,,N/A,,,0,0
1323,Expense,4/3/2013,1129,N/A,Bell,Cash on Hand,0,0
1323,Expense,4/3/2013,,N/A,,Telephone,406.02,60.6697
1323,Expense,4/3/2013,,N/A,,,406.02,60.6697
1323,Expense,4/3/2013,,N/A,,,0,0
1324,Expense,1/3/2013,1130,N/A,Consulting,Cash on Hand,0,0
1324,Expense,1/3/2013,,N/A,,IT Services,17.9307,2.6793
1324,Expense,1/3/2013,,N/A,,,17.9307,2.6793
1324,Expense,1/3/2013,,N/A,,,0,0
1325,Expense,6/3/2013,1131,N/A,Utilities,Cash on Hand,0,0
1325,Expense,6/3/2013,,N/A,,Utilities,68.8083,10.2817
1325,Expense,6/3/2013,,N/A,,,68.8083,10.2817
1325,Expense,6/3/2013,,N/A,,,0,0
```

This does not correspond to your expected output, but since your expected output was not in accordance with the specifications in the first place, I didn't try to interpret that too much.